# docker python Database could not translate host name

Tags: python, docker, docker-network

When i'm trying to run python image :

```
docker run --name pytana -p 5050:5050 -it  --network city  pythonbac
```

i get error

```
peewee.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db_container_name" to address: Name or service not known
```

there is connect in source

```
db = PostgresqlDatabase('postgres', user='postgres', password='postgres',
                            host='db_container_name', port=5432)
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3-onbuild
EXPOSE 5050
CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

db docker compose file

```
# This configuration is intended for development purpose, it's **your** responsibility to harden it for production
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:13.1
    volumes:
        - testdataloc:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    container_name: db_container_name 
    networks:
      - city  
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
volumes:
    testdataloc:
        external: true            
networks:
  city:
    # Use a custom driver
    driver: bridge
```

My os wind10.
Additional info when i use nettwork host and put host to localhost it connects.

```
docker network inspect city
    [
        {
            "Name": "city",
            "Id": "1734484676b63915c041bc0128d1a5b9d340cb4b76878eb54e11ea7995c0e1de",
            "Created": "2021-03-10T14:27:03.6343643Z",
            "Scope": "local",
            "Driver": "bridge",
            "EnableIPv6": false,
            "IPAM": {
                "Driver": "default",
                "Options": {},
                "Config": [
                    {
                        "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                        "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Internal": false,
            "Attachable": false,
            "Ingress": false,
            "ConfigFrom": {
                "Network": ""
            },
            "ConfigOnly": false,
            "Containers": {},
            "Options": {},
            "Labels": {}
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Could you show results of  `docker network inspect city` command?

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev Can't add more code sample added as  text.

Comment: If you `docker network ls`, has Compose actually named the network something else (`dirname_city`, probably)?  Can you include the application in the Compose setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes ther is docker-compose_city docker_city.So actualy my base not in city network yes?

Comment: I got the point now I can handle it.

Comment: @SultanZhumatayev from the `docker network inspect city` output it looks like the required container is not active. Do `docker ps -a` to check if db_container_name was even created. If it was created do `docker logs db_container_name` to check if there were any errors

Comment: @SultanZhumatayev as an alternative to docker compose you can do all in one line command `docker run --name x_db --network=x_net -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xpaswd_12344 -e POSTGRES_USER=x_user -e POSTGRES_DB=x_db -d postgres` Is is from PostgreSQL Image documentation. I often use it to create temporary dbs in my projects.